# ImportError: No module named pymongo in a remote server

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have installed pymongo on my local system, and am trying to run a script on a remote machine. However, I am getting a `ImportError: No module named pymongo` error on importing pymongo, while logged in to the remote server. It is however, working perfectly on my local system, i.e., without logging in to the server. I have tried appending a system path `sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages')`, and it is still not working. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is pymongo installed on the remote machine? It looks like the path you gave is the local one (unless the remote machine is also running OS X). I really recommend virtualenv for managing dependencies and easily installing them on local and remote environments.

Comment: Since everything my company does works on this very machine, I guess pymongo is installed on it. Also, installing (using pip) says gives "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pymongo in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages". And I am using Fedora 17.

Comment: Can you provide output of this code 

`python -c 'import sys; print sys.path; print sys.version'`

Comment: @DenisNikanorov, ['', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib64/python26.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.6', '/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info']
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jul 10 2013, 22:48:45) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]

Comment: @Apoorv Ashutosh, I think you configured something wrong because you wrote that pip says `pymongo in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages` but yoy run python 2.6